# Bug tracking system that can calculate velocity

Tags: project-management

I am looking for a task planning/bug tracking system with decent scheduling capabilities. It should:

- Support subtasks/dependencies.
- Be able to create Gantt chart from the dependencies and assigned resources.
- Be able to track average velocity of each developer (average ratio of actual time to original estimate, as per [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html))
- Should be accessible by all team members (so not a local thing like MS Project) and preferably require as few clicks as possible to maintain the information.

Obviously [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/Fogbugz/) can do it, but I am not sure we could persuade the boss to shell out the (or any) money. To be honest while he wants to improve planning, with the constant changes of plans the benefit may not indeed be worth much money.

We are currently looking at [ClockingIt](http://www.clockingit.com/). It can produce reasonablish Gantt chart, but I am not sure it can track the velocity. I would think some of the major systems like RedMine, Trac or Mantis may have time-tracking plugin with appropriate capabilities, but the descriptions are often not very good and I can't try everything out.

So I'd like to ask whether you know which system can do it or does have a plugin for it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late for the OP, but others may find it useful. At my workplace we use Atlassian JIRA. It is easy to use; has good velocity tracking and bug and task tracking capabilities. It has nice features to plan which bugs/tasks will be worked on in a given time period. A drawback is that Gantt charts are not built in, however they are available as an add-on from 3rd party vendors see [here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.polscheit.jira.plugins.gantt/server/overview) for an example. It may also be helpful to read this comparison between Fogbugz and JIRA [here](http://movingfulcrum.com/why-fogbugz-lost-to-jira/).